# Atributo json_array vazio ao persistir no BD

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine-2, symfony4

Boas Galeri.

Estou com um problema curioso ao utilizar DoctrineFixturesBundle.
Tenho uma classe **Application** do tipo `Entity Class` que mapeia para a tabela *sistema*.
Nessa classe há um atributo chamado **options** que é do tipo `json_array` mapeada para a coluna de `sistema opções` e eu a inicializo como um `ArrayCollection`.
Options está *logicamente* codificada para que cada elemento desta coleção seja um Objeto (Entidade OptionAttribute).
Fiz desta forma porque precisava ter um Form que possuisse a capacidade de adicionar/remover/editar cada elemento desta coleção, e então criei a Entity OptionAttribute que não está mapeada no Banco de Dados.
Criei os FormType tanto para Application quanto para OptionAttribute e tudo funcionou a contento.

Agora fui criar Fixtures para a Entidade Application e a coluna sistema opções fica apenas com '{}', ou seja, vazia. Não há erro de execução, apenas não está persistindo a coleção de entidades OptionAttribute.

Segue as classes

A classe de fixtures para Application

```
class ApplicationFixtures extends Fixture
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $oManager)
    {
        $types = ['TextType', 'TextareaType', 'EmailType', 'IntegerType', 'MoneyType',
            'NumberType', 'UrlType', 'TelType', 'DateType', 'DateTimeType', 'TimeType', 'PercentType',
            'SearchType', 'BirthdayType', 'CheckboxType', 'FileType'];
        $appsAlias = [1 => 'Facebook', 'Twitter', 'Instagram', 'Tumbler', 'Tinder'];
        foreach ($appsAlias as $k => $app) {
            /* @var $application Application */
            $application = new Application();
            $application->setName('Application Number ' . $k)
                ->setIsActive(true)
                ->setAlias($app);

            $rand_keys = array_rand($types, 5);

            foreach ($rand_keys as $typesKey) {
                $optionAttribute = new OptionAttribute();
                $optionAttribute->setName('Option ' . str_replace('Type', '', $types[$typesKey]))
                    ->setDefaultValue('Default Value for Option ' . $typesKey)
                    ->setRequired(($typesKey % 2 == 1))
                    ->setType($types[$typesKey]);

                $application->addOption($optionAttribute);
            }

            $oManager->persist($application);
        }
        $oManager->flush();
    }

}
```

Entidade Application

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="sistema")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Application
{

    // Several attributes...

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection|OptionAttribute[]
     * @ORM\Column(name="sistema_opcoes", type="json_array", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $options;

    public function __construct() {
        // ...
        $this->options = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    // Several getters and setters for ordinary fields
    /**
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getOptions()
    {
        $options = new ArrayCollection();
        foreach($this->options as $k => $value) {
            /* @var $option OptionAttribute */
            $option = new OptionAttribute();
            $option->unserialize($value);
            $options->add($option);
        }
        return $options;
    }

    /**
     * @param ArrayCollection $options
     * @return Application
     */
    public function setOptions(ArrayCollection $options)
    {
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            $this->addOption($option);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionAttribute $option
     * @return $this
     */
    public function addOption(OptionAttribute $option)
    {
        $this->options->add($option->serialize());
        return $this;
    }

}
```

E a Entidade OptionAttribute

```
class OptionAttribute implements \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $defaultvalue;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     */
    private $required = false;

    // Getters and Setters

    /** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->name,
            $this->defaultvalue,
            $this->type,
            $this->required,
        ));
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->name,
            $this->defaultvalue,
            $this->type,
            $this->required,
            ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }
}
```

Onde será que estou errando???

Answer (score 0):

Para quem tiver o mesmo problema.

Percebi que a conversão de **ArrayCollection** para *json_array* não funcionava como eu esperava e então alterei o código para que o atributo fosse preenchido apenas com o tipo `array` no atributo em questão e tudo funcionou como esperado.

Não precisei alterar o método `getOptions`.

Segue as alterações

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="sistema")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Application
{

    // Several attributes...

    /**
     * @var array
     * @ORM\Column(name="sistema_opcoes", type="json_array", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $options;

    public function __construct() {
        // ...
        $this->options = [];
    }

    // Several getters and setters for ordinary fields

    /**
     * @param ArrayCollection $options
     * @return Application
     */
    public function setOptions(ArrayCollection $options)
    {
        $this->options = [];
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            $this->addOption($option);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionAttribute $option
     * @return $this
     */
    public function addOption(OptionAttribute $option)
    {
        $options = $this->getOptions();
        if ($options->contains($option)) {
            return;
        }
        $this->options[]= ($option->serialize());
        return $this;
    }

}
```

A partir desse ponto consegui utilizar a classe de Fixture normalmente.